Power BI Time Series Oscillating Between Same Number
I have a power BI time series chart showing an average dollar amount over time. The average is constant so I was expecting to see a straight line. However, the line is going up and down. I thought maybe this was a rounding issue so I changed the field format to have more decimal places. However, when I checked what the high and low values are, they are exactly the same. Why is Power BI doing this? Has anyone ever had this happen before?
Time Series Screen Shot
I tried to see if it was a rounding issue. It doesn't look like one to me.
I also tried making sure that the joins in my model are correct. I believe they are.

What are the fields you are using for the line char visual?
